# changing app from free to paid in android, how does this affect previous downloaders?

Tags: android, google-play

So Ive decided to turn my free app into a paid app, the question I have is how does this affect people who previously downloaded my app, for example If I release an update in the future will the people who already dowloaded the app when it was free have to pay to download the update? this I would like to avoid as I dont want bad ratings in android market, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once an app is free on the Android Market it cannot be made a paid app. You can unpublish it, and you can publish the app under a new package name for a fee, but your existing users will not auto-update to it.

Comment: What Mah said. If you had published one before you should have noticed where it said that.

Comment: There's actually no fee for publishing it under a new package name.

Comment: @kabuko -- I wasn't saying there was a fee to publish, I was saying that the new package could have a fee for users, as the poster was looking to charge ;)

Answer (score 1):

@mah is right, though there is a way around that limitation - instead of replacing your free version with a paid version, you could implement in-app purchasing to license the additional functionality. Now, you can have the free, limited version and it is simple for the user to upgrade within the app to the full, paid version.