# After update the free android app to paid, can old users use the app without paying

Tags: android, google-play

I have a free android app and i want to convert it to paid. Not with free and paid versions, just paid.
But i'm not sure when i update my free app to paid on googleplay, should old users pay for paid version ? or will they use without any payment with update ? thanks in advance.

Comment: Hopefully this helps you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693918/changing-app-from-free-to-paid-in-android-how-does-this-affect-previous-downloa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Play does not allow you to change a free app to paid. The only way to do this is to release a completely new app with a different Android package name. This automatically implies that existing users of the original free app will have to pay for the new paid app.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change free app to paid app. Its mentioned in the launch checklist.
http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html

> Once you publish an app as a free app, you cannot change it to being a
>   priced app. However, you can still sell in-app products and
>   subscriptions through Google Play's In-app Billing service.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this you must up new app with different package name with same name

Answer (score 0):

As noted by others, it is not permitted to update a free app to a paid one.  However, you can add in-app payments and then charge for enhanced features of your app.